Does Azure Speech Translation API expose the language detected key?
I am building a simple Python application using continuous speech translation through the Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK. Translation and detection between languages works as far as I can tell. My goal is to update the UI according to the detected language. However, I cannot get a detected language signal. The docs say that for Python continuous language detection works. Can I get a signal for the detected language?
My question is about:
speechsdk.languageconfig.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(self.detectable_languages)

I am setting the languages according to the SDK specs using the language code and locale:
detectable_languages = ["en-US", "es-MX"]

This is where I am configuring the translation recognizer:

speech_translation_config.set_property(property_id=speechsdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_LanguageIdMode, value='Continuous')

def configure(self):
        self.speech_translation_config = self.init_speech_translation_config()
        self.audio_config = self.set_audio_source()
        self.auto_detect_source_language_config = speechsdk.languageconfig.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(self.detectable_languages)
        print("Detectable languages set in AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig:")
        print(self.auto_detect_source_language_config.language)
        self.translation_recognizer = self.init_translation_recognizer()
        self.set_event_callbacks()


When I run my app I get this output:
Error in executing callback: 'AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig' object has no attribute 'language'

It seems to me I should get a signal for the machines having detected "en-US" or "es-MX". Can someone tell me if the API for Python is limited in this regard or if the detected language is not exposed for a reason I am not aware of? Thank you!

Can you share your complete code in the question?

I tried the below code and successfully detected the "en-US" and "es-MX" languages.
Code :
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import sys
 
speech_key = "<speech_key>"
service_region = "<speech_region>"
 
detectable_languages = ["en-US", "es-MX"]
auto_detect_source_language_config = speechsdk.languageconfig.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(languages=detectable_languages)
 
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
 
def main():
    recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config,
                                            audio_config=audio_config,
                                            auto_detect_source_language_config=auto_detect_source_language_config)
 
    print("Session started")
    print("Continuous recognition started, press Enter to stop...")
    while True:
        try:
            print("Speech start detected")
            result = recognizer.recognize_once()
            print("Speech end detected")
 
            if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                text = result.text
                language_result = result.properties[speechsdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_AutoDetectSourceLanguageResult]
                if language_result:
                    detected_language = language_result
                    print("Recognized:", text)
                    print("Detected language:", detected_language)
                else:
                    print("Could not detect the language.")
            elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
                print("No speech could be recognized")
            elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
                cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
                print("Speech recognition canceled:", cancellation_details.reason)
                if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                    print("Error details:", cancellation_details.error_details)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting...")
            sys.exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: {0}".format(e))
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output :


@serxio Have you tried the solution I provided?

Hi, Dasari. I will indeed try this solution and mark it up once verified.
